# Storing the Django project with the PostgreSQL database on GitHub

Tags: python, django, git, postgresql, github

I changed the database from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL in my Django project. Is it possible to store my new database in the GitHub repository so that after cloning and running by the command

`python manage.py runserver`

the project has started with the whole database?

Comment: No, that's not possible and also not advisable for SQlite. But Django offers fixtures to initialize the database.

Comment: If you want to be able to recreate your postgres db, look at [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgdump.html) and [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgrestore.html). You can check the output  of the former into your repo if you should so desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save the database as such, you can instead create fixtures to be run. Whenever someone will clone the project, he/she can simple run those fixtures to populate the database.

Comment: Any advice / source on how to create such fixtures ?

Will I have to change the settings in DATABASES in settings.py then?

Comment: @KazimierzMigdał Have you read the docs? Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata  and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata

Comment: No, database settings etc. need not be changed. You can follow one of these links to do that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/initial-data/